# vectorize a filter to a subsequence of an array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, filter, vectorization

I have a vector,"a", and a filter,"b".Both of those vectors contain only 0 or 1.
I would like to transform "a" such that any sequence of 1 only starts when b is at 1.

I have illustrated this using a loop but, as my vectors are huge, it is extremely inefficient.

The result I would like is stored in "r".

```
a=[0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1];

b=[0;0;0;0;1;0;1;0;0;1;0;1;0;1;1;0;0;0;0];

r=[0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1];

for i=2:length(a)

    if a(i)==1  &&a(i-1)==0 && b(i)==0        
       a(i)=a(i-1);          
    end
end

assert(sum(a==r)==length(a))
```

Comment: If I have interpreted this correctly, you have a bit of a problem because the `if` statement expression depends upon the result of the previous iteration.  This is obviously going to be problematic if you vectorise it since you are, at least conceptually, performing the operation on all elements at the same time.

Comment: Also, just a note: `(sum(a==r)==length(a)` could be written `all(a==r)`, which is a bit nicer.

Comment: you are right, it's problematic but not impossible. there are tricks to deal with such issues (http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/programs/Matlab/tricks.html, look for the chapter "Vectorise the following, where elements depend on previous ones"). In my case i am trying to apply it in a more complex way

Comment: That's a little different though, because the algorithm could be expressed in a different way (using a cumulative sum) which did allow it to be vectorised.  I'm not sure this can be done here, although I'm not going to post that as an answer as I'm not totally confident ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-liner:

```
r = a;
r([false; diff(a)>0 & b(2:end)==0]) = 0;
```

Please note that you need to adapt the code for row vectors (this works for column vectors).

Comment: it produces :<br>[0;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1]<br/> instead of [0;0;0;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1]

Comment: the 4 th element is not correct because using in your code diff(a)>0 would only remove the first one of the sequence of one, but not the followings